c++ static_cast to virtual base in runtime
Suppose we have such code:
struct Granny {
  int g;
};
struct Mom : virtual Granny {
  int m;
};
struct Son : Mom {
  int s;
};

int main() {
  int x;
  std::cin >> x;
  Mom* mom = (x ? new Son : new Mom);
  Granny* granny = static_cast<Granny*>(mom);
}

Classes are not polymorphic, so Granny doesn't has a vtable. Now, depending on x, there can be different memory layout under mom pointer. So, sub-object Granny will be shifted from the object start by either 16 or 12 bytes.
Question: is static_cast instead of "simply shift pointer" compiled in "dereference vptr(vtable) in mom object, then look at some index to find virtual offset, then, finally, shift pointer by this offset"? So, would static_cast has 2 additional runtime operations? If not, please, explain what happens.

How are you planning to delete the object pointed out by mom later? Yet another if with a cast back to Son if needed? If so, why not use polymorphism? Where do the quotes "simply shift pointer" etc. come from? I don't know what that means.

you seem to care about performance. Then you need to consider that your code is not doing anything with granny and that the cast does not have to do anything.

optimizers are beasts. Its is impossible to predict what they will do. But if a human can see a way to translate your code in a way that the cast needs 0 operations, then the compiler surely can see that as well. Further note that the vtable is an implementation detail. Nothing actually requires the compiler to do anything with a vtable or vptr

@TedLyngmo I understand that Granny or Mom should have a virtual destructor. I think the purpose of my question is static_cast and what it does in described case. So I decided not to clutter up the text and code with irrelevant things. About "simply shift pointer", I think that without virtual inheritance granny, mom and son would be placed one by one, so static_cast in assembler would be just "shift pointer mom by x bytes back or forward(0 bytes in that case)"

@463035818_is_not_an_ai "you seem to care about performance". My purpose is to understand behaviour of static_cast, not to find most optimized way to do such stuff. "optimizers are beasts." Here I suppose compiler cannot do any oprimizations. "vtable is an implementation detail" Yes, but I now rely on my general knowledge about vtables and inheritance. So I may not to understand how it works(in such case, please, explain me)

then vtable and offsets are even less relevant. The behavior is that the pointer resulting from the cast points to the Granny subobject of the object. The vtable and vptr is not "behavior" but implementation details that you cannot rely on

dont get me wrong. I understand where you are coming from, but imho it is important to understand the limitation of the answer you are looking for.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I understand that this is really abstract question due to implementation of vtables and virtual inheritance is not standardized at all. But I am not satisfied with  "result of static_cast is a pointer to Granny", I want to know its mechanism and in more details what happens under hood, even with impl. defined vtables etc.

yes that I understand. My point is just that what you see implemented without optimziations has little to nothing to do with the implementation once you do turn them on.

Absolutely agree. Thank you!

You can just throw both cases into Compiler explorer:
Granny* from_Son(Son* x) { return static_cast<Granny *>(x); }
Granny* from_Mom(Mom* x) { return static_cast<Granny *>(x); }

compiles to the following three instructions (with error checking around it):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]    
        add     rdi, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     rax, rdi

In this snippet, rdi is x. [rdi] is your vtable, and the offset to Granny is thus stored 24 bytes before the vtable.

Thank you! Probably, I should learn basic assembler to check it by myself and to not ask such type of questions here
